# Missing rosidl type support for custom message in Python [Eloquent]

Tags: ros, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**What I am trying to achieve:** within my workspace, create a `ament_cmake` package with custom messages called `navigation_msgs` and publish them in an `ament_python` package.

**What works:** `ros2 interface show navigation_msgs/EulerAttitude` correctly displays my message. I am also able to import the message in Python `from navigation_msgs.msg import EulerAttitude`. Furthermore, within the same package I can publish built-in messages like `geometry_msgs` (`Vector3`)

**What does not work:** when trying to `ros2 run pub_node not_working` I get a `typesupport` error (the trace is below). It is raised when I call `create_publisher` in the `NotWorkingNode` constructor.

**Setup**: Ubuntu 18.04 with ROS3 Eloquent from APT. `ros2 doctor` works. (in fact the problem if the same with Dashing, also from APT.)

**How to reproduce:** attached code is a minimal workspace with `ros2 run pub_node working` and `ros2 run pub_node working`. `working` should work and `notworking` should give the error.

> ```
> TCantelobre@1044617:~/bug$ ros2 run pub_node  notworking 
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rosidl_generator_py/import_type_support_impl.py", line 40, in import_type_support
>         return importlib.import_module(module_name, package=pkg_name)
>      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
>         return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
>      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
>      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
>      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
>      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
>      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>   ImportError: /home/TCantelobre/bug/install/navigation_msgs/lib/libnavigation_msgs__rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c.so: undefined symbol: rosidl_typesupport_fastrtps_c__get_message_type_support_handle__std_msgs__msg__Header
> ```

> ```
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> ```

> ```
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "/home/TCantelobre/bug/install/pub_node/lib/pub_node/notworking", line 11, in <module>
> ```

```
load_entry_point('pub-node==0.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'notworking')()
```

> ```
>      File "/home/TCantelobre/bug/install/pub_node/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pub_node/not_working.py", line 28, in main
> ```

```
not_working_node = NotWorkingNode()
```

> ```
>      File "/home/TCantelobre/bug/install/pub_node/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pub_node/not_working.py", line 16, in __init__
> ```

```
self.publisher = self.create_publisher(EulerAttitude, "attitude", 100)
```

> ```
>      File "/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rclpy/node.py", line 1094, in create_publisher
> ```

```
check_for_type_support(msg_type)
```

> ```
>      File "/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rclpy/type_support.py", line 29, in check_for_type_support
> ```

```
msg_type.__class__.__import_type_support__()
```

> ```
>      File "/home/TCantelobre/bug/install/navigation_msgs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/navigation_msgs/msg/_euler_attitude.py", line 27, in __import_type_support__
>           module = import_type_support('navigation_msgs')
>      File "/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rosidl_generator_py/import_type_support_impl.py", line 42, in import_type_support
>           raise UnsupportedTypeSupport(pkg_name)
>  rosidl_generator_py.import_type_support_impl.UnsupportedTypeSupport: Could not import 'rosidl_typesupport_c' for package 'navigation_msgs'
> ```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338825/missing-rosidl-type-support-for-custom-message-in-python-%5Beloquent%5D/) by [TCantelobre](https://answers.ros.org/users/49865/tcantelobre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2019-11-28

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TCantelobre](https://answers.ros.org/users/49865/tcantelobre/) on 2019-11-29**:
Quick comment, I can't upload the files because I don't have enough reputation... would be happy to put them in a Google Drive or something if necessary. Looking forward to hearing from you!

**Comment by [charvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/33083/charvi/) on 2020-02-02**:
Any solution to this problem, as I am also facing the same while building custom msg in dashing , using cyclonedds rmw ?

**Comment by [doekaschi](https://answers.ros.org/users/52328/doekaschi/) on 2020-07-16**:
I also do have the same issue, however I am creating a custom service using eloquent, not a message using dashing. Has there been any progress concerning this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same issue and did some research to fix it. For me, the problem was, that I had not declared the dependencies of the message(s) correctly when defining it in the CMakeLists.txt. For furhter info, please check out this question that solved my issue: https://answers.ros.org/question/326008/ros2-run-symbol-not-found-on-custom-msg/

---

Originally posted by [doekaschi](https://answers.ros.org/users/52328/doekaschi/) with karma: 78 on 2020-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [charvi](https://answers.ros.org/users/33083/charvi/) on 2020-09-21**:
Thank you @doekaschi , I also did the same to solve this issue.